# ethervault.io has shut down - are my coins all gone/stolen?

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet

an online wallet i used for about 6 months called www.ethervault.io has recently completely shut down - no website, phone numbers disconnected, email all bouncing back.

how do i access my coins? have they been stolen by the site's owners? seriously worried! please help!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how ethervault.io worked.

Whoever has the private key for an account is control of the funds in that account. If you have the private key for your account, then you can access it using any tool. If you don't have the private key, then you never actually had an Ethereum account. (Perhaps ethervault.io kept everyone's funds in their own account(s) and kept track of who was owed what in a database somewhere.)

From skimming a [cached copy of their FAQ](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:m8v61lt2-u4J:https://www.ethervault.io/faq+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), it looks to me like your funds were in *their* account(s), so I think you're out of luck unless you can track them down and perhaps take legal action:

> Can I see the balance of my EtherVault address with a third party application?
>
> Your deposit address is connected to your account forever. All deposits made to this address will be added to your account balance. However we don’t guarantee that coins will reside on this address. Due to our system architecture and security measures coins will be moved to other addresses (cold storage) shortly after deposits, but it does not affect your account balance. You can still spend all your coins at any time.

Comment: hi @smarx are you saying you know something about ethervault? as far as i can tell, they've done a runner and i have no access to my coins as i never had a private key. do you know how i can access my coins that were stored there?

Comment: Everything I know about EtherVault is contained in this answer.