Ethervault.io has been counting my staking days in -
I had staked coins in this platform for 365days. The days left and the platform is still counting them with “-“ and I can’t withdraw them. What’s happening?

The site looks suspicious at best. The domain was a scam a few years back https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41918/ethervault-io-has-shut-down-are-my-coins-all-gone-stolen.
